# Direct sum of a module and an infinitely generated free module is free

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

In the answer of [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27406/free-resolution-dimension) post, it states that $P\oplus F$ is a free module, where $F$ is an infinitely generated free module and $P$ is projective. How can I check the freeness of $P\oplus F$?  Does this hold if $P$ isn't assumed to be projective ?

Comment: Do you know the characterization of projective modules as direct summands of free modules? That's crucial here. It should be evident that this does not hold for arbitrary $P$. For example: free modules are torsion-free, but if $P$ would have torsion, so does $P\oplus F$.

Comment: There are **three** answers in that post.

Comment: I think that, while there are some "one-line-read" things about this question (namely, the answer to the second question is clearly "No" because of what @Thorgott says), there are some details in [the answer of interest](https://mathoverflow.net/a/27415) that can use some further inspection. Namely, it's been pointed out in the comments that $P\oplus R^{\oplus \kappa}$ might not be free for all projective modules $P$ and infinite cardinals $\kappa$. The author of the answer seems to have realised that, but it's unclear how he addressed the issue. [continues]

Comment: [continuation] For instance, if we call $b(P)$ the least cardinality of a generating set for $P$, then the claim is easy to prove under the further assumtpion that $\kappa\ge b(P)$. On the other hand, if $P$ is free, then the claim is true for all $\kappa$. Personally, I'd be curious to read an answer to this "more focused version" of the question: "Is there is some projective $R$-module $P$ such that there is some $\kappa\ge\aleph_0$ such that $P\oplus R^{\oplus \kappa}$ isn't free? Equivalently, is $P\oplus R^{\oplus \aleph_0}$ free for all projective modules $P$?"

Comment: Turns out that the answer [is not new to "critique"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2162714/direct-sum-of-projective-and-free-modules?rq=1)!